# Why I sometime get Coroutine was never awaited when I use asyncio.run

Tags: python, django, python-asyncio, coroutine

This error is rare, but still present. This happens when two or more requests are sent at the same time.

I try to do it:

```py
adapter = OperatorCreator.create(
    title=operator.slug,
    api_key=operator.api_discount[0]
)

terminals = asyncio.run(
    adapter.find_terminals(locality=locality), debug=True
)

return terminal
```

Adapter:

```py
async def find_terminals(self, locality: Locality, session: aiohttp.ClientSession = None) -> Mapping[str, Terminal]:
    if 'dpd_terminals' in cache:
        terminal_list = await sync_to_async(cache.get)('dpd_terminals')
    else:
        terminal_list = await self.add_terminals_from_request_to_cache()
    terminals = terminal_list[str(locality.kladr)]
    return terminals
```

And then sometime I get:

> django_1        | /app/project/apps/geo/services.py:383: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'CdekAdapter.find_terminals' was never awaited

> django_1        |   adapter.find_terminals(locality=locality)

> django_1        | RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run `This function cannot be called when another asyncio event loop is running in the same thread.` You literally do what Python docs tell you not to.

Comment: @mattia-righetti, Can you suggest something?